# HOw to SELECT * (all) which date start from the last day of last month to the first day of next month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

use PHP and MySQL and want to use SELECT statement which date_post(datetime variable) start at the last date of last month and to date the first day of next month, help me please.

Thank you in advance.

```
my database: 'id', 'content', 'image', 'date_post',
```

etc. and I try to use

```
$today = getdate();
$thisyear=$today['year'];
$thismon=$today['mon'];
$date_start=$thisyear.'-'.$thismon.'-01';
$date_end=$thisyear.'-'.($thismon+1).'-01';
$sql="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_post, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datepost
      FROM my_table
      WHERE date_post BETWEEN date('$date_start') 
        AND date('$date_end')
      ORDER BY date_post DESC";
```

Comment: Please include some details about your database schema, and also any existing SQL that you tried.

Comment: my database: 'id', 'content', 'image', 'date_post', etc. and I try to use         $today = getdate();
$thisyear=$today['year'];
$thismon=$today['mon'];
$date_start=$thisyear.'-'.$thismon.'-01';
$date_end=$thisyear.'-'.($thismon+1).'-01';
$sql="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_post, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datepost 
      FROM my_table
      WHERE date_post BETWEEN date('$date_start') AND date('$date_end') 
      ORDER BY date_post DESC";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes with one query in MySQL, without any PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE DATE(`date_post`) >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, CONCAT('%Y-%m-', DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))))
AND DATE(`date_post`) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01');
```

Comment: to garvey: thank you but it return error:Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...

Comment: @AJ OP, Hmmm. I've tested it in my dbmysqlforge. Can you get me your php code with calling this query? And what version of MySQl are you using?

Comment: I try to use this(it's work) -re move single qoutes form date_post, thank you very much.     $sql="SELECT * FROM entry
          WHERE DATE(date_post) >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, CONCAT('%Y-%m-', DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))) AND DATE(date_post) <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')";

Comment: more info:phpMyAdmin - 2.10.3
MySQL client version: 5.0.51a
Used PHP extensions: mysql

Comment: @AJ OP - Click on the little up arrow next the answer. It looks like you accepted the answer. however, which is an even better way to show support.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring that the query will not scan the full table but will use the index of `date_post` (if there is one!):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE date_post < LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
                   + INTERVAL 2 DAY
  AND date_Post >= LAST_DAY( LAST_DAY( CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

If it is run today ( `2011-07-01` ), it will give all datetimes between `2011-06-31 00:00:00` and `2011-08-01 23:59:59`.